# Answering a related question

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I find the following happens quite often:

- I spend a while trying to solve Problem A
- I search and find SO questions relating to Problem A, with accepted answers, but none of the suggestions help
- I discover I actually have Problem B, which manifests in a similar way to Problem A, and solve it
- Now that I know the underlying issue, I search for Problem B and find a more relevant question
- I answer or update the question on Problem B as appropriate

My question is: Is it acceptable to also answer the question on Problem A, since this is the question I actually found when I had not yet solved my issue, so seems more likely to help others in a similar position in future?

Concrete example here:
 - [My answer to a question on Problem B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986147/target-not-running-when-using-beforetargets-build-on-build-server/31424691#31424691) (the question I only found after identifying and solving the issue)
 - [My answer to a question on Problem A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218374/msbuild-build-package-including-extra-files/31424834#31424834) (the question I actually found when I still needed help)

Is the second link good/bad/neutral etiquette? - I'm aware there are related questions in the sidebar, but at the time of writing the two example questions above aren't connected in this way. Also I tend not to notice these due to 'sidebar blindness' (conditioned response to internet adverts).

Comment: In your newest post you are referring to answers as comments, which is inaccurate. Answers are answers, comments go underneath questions and answers, _like this_. Also, some of the intro isn't required in an answer, as it doesn't add value, it's just noise. I don't see a problem with the answer and linking to your other answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've tightened up my preamble and removed erroneous uses of 'comment'/'commenting'.

Comment: That's much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak authoritatively on etiquette, but on several occasions I have been helped by answers to Problem B written on Problem A as you describe.

A good example is [this Gulp question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224252/looking-for-way-to-copy-files-in-gulp-and-rename-based-on-parent-directory). The answer below the accepted one knows that it is not the answer to the original question but is helpful to people who land there from search (it now has more upvotes than the actual answer!). There is even a [brief discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224252/looking-for-way-to-copy-files-in-gulp-and-rename-based-on-parent-directory#comment50056424_22133922) of the issue your question raises in the comments on that answer.

Being helpful to anyone that might reasonably arrive at the question via search makes the practice OK in my book.